# Java Regex String: Check if ip:port string contains a valid IPv4 or DNS address

Tags: java, regex, dns

Basically, I'm trying to check if a String is a valid IP address without using external libraries in Java (it doesn't have to be an IP with a working host at the other end; it can be an unused one too). I can't check if it's an IP address because I would like DNS support as well. Since the following options are valid:

- 1.2.3.4:55555
- localhost:1
- google.com:12345
- 1.2.abc:54321 (is this valid?)

but the following aren't valid:

- 1.2.3.4 (no port)
- 1.2:34 (not an IP address)
- local host:12345 (space)
- 8.8.8.8:abc (not numbers in port slot)
- stackoverflow.com:234.5 (basically only numbers should follow the :
- localhost:65536 (port number out of bounds)

At this moment (I will continue to update this), i do the following checks:

```
host != null;
!host.contains(" ");
host.contains(":");
```

Other checks I think can be done but I don't know how to do:

*Contains 1 and only 1 colon
*If it only contains numbers and periods, it must contain 3 and only 3 periods, 4 numbers, and each number has to be between 0 and 255
*Number following colon is a number and is between 0 and 65535

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use a regex like this :

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IpCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^"
                + "(((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}" // Domain name
                + "|"
                + "localhost" // localhost
                + "|"
                + "(([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3})[0-9]{1,3})" // Ip
                + ":"
                + "[0-9]{1,5}$"); // Port

        System.out.println(p.matcher("1.2.3.4:55555").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("localhost:1").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("google.com:12345").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("1.2.abc:54321").matches());

        System.out.println(p.matcher("1.2.3.4").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("1.2:34").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("local host:12345").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("stackoverflow.com:234.5").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("localhost:65536").matches());

    }

}
```

Prints :

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
true
```

It works except for the port range, for this I would suggest that you extract the port number if any, and outside the regex. My opinion is that Regex is not made to test integers range (still possible)

Comment: Some day you're going to have to explain to me how this works :-P

Comment: How to use it only for 1.2.3.4:55555